# All values deleting from Temp table, not just one specified

Tags: sql, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to setup some data driven subscriptions and running into a problem.  Lets say I want to run a report for invoices from yesterday.  There are four invoices and each invoice will have any number of of transactions.  Report will need to run four times.  I have the following code to load up the invoices into a `#Temp`.  From there it should loop the invoices, query appropriate info, delete that invoice from `#Temp` and move on to the next invoice.

```
SELECT invoice
INTO #Temp
FROM dbo.InvoiceTable
WHERE CreatedOnDate between today and yesterday  --obv not real

DECLARE @Invoice VARCHAR(25) 

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #Temp)

Begin

Select  top 1 @Invoice =  Invoice From #Temp  

select name, date, amount etc
where InvoiceNo = @Invoice

Delete from #Temp WHERE @Invoice = InvoiceNo

End

drop table #Temp
```

This all seems to make sense and when I run it in SSMS I get four different result sets.  However when setting up the data driven subscription it's only running the first invoice no for the number of transactions for that invoice.  Nine transactions, nine emails with all the same report and no other reports for the remaining 3 invoices.  Is my `WHILE EXISTS` out of place?

Comment: Loop looks OK. Are you sure you have more than one Invoice in dbo.InvoiceTable within the specified date range?

Comment: @rwking  I do.  Like I said, I can run it in SSMS and get the four different results sets.  So figured it'd work no problem in SSRS

Comment: Are you executing this as a stored procedure, or do you just have the code embedded in your data set?

Comment: Just inserting the code into the data driven sub.  No SP.